# Problem of using package "gmapping" in groovy

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a new pkg and need a dependency on gmapping pkg
After the new pkg created with `catkin_create_pkg uu roscpp gmapping`
when I do catkin-make,errors occured like following:
"
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gmapping" with any
of the following names:

```
gmappingConfig.cmake
gmapping-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "gmapping" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"gmapping_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"gmapping" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.
......
"

> Any help??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61685/problem-of-using-package-%22gmapping%22-in-groovy/) by [Shifaye](https://answers.ros.org/users/4374/shifaye/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

gmapping is not catkinized yet. You can only depend on catkin packages from catkin, so this won't work.

You can switch to rosbuild if you really need gmapping as a dependency.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0